# Salvar Log de operações no banco com campo de usuário do sistema

Tags: banco-de-dados, sqlite, log

Gostaria de saber qual a maneira de por meio de triggers no banco eu consiga além de salvar as operações realizadas e em qual tabela realizada também o usuário logado no sistema (não o usuário do banco, se o usuário do sistema) no momento da alteração.

No caso eu teria:
[Tabela de Usuários] [Tabela de produtos] [Tabela de Log]

Todas as alterações feitas na tabela de usuários ou de produtos deveria gerar uma linha na tabela de log, com:

data, operação (I,U,D), tabela, usuário(tabela de usuario), id do registro modificado.

Answer (score 0):

Por triggers pelo que sei vc teria que criar uma para cada tabela.
dependendo do sistema é melhor vc fazer algum método que toda execução em banco envie o registro pra tabela de LOG

Comment: É, sei que teria que criar um trigger pra cada tabela. O problema que estou tento, é conseguir pegar o usuário do sistema que fez a alteração na tabela por uma trigger. Não sei se estou sendo claro, mas é esse meu problema. Obrigado pela resposta.